# Name for the expression $f''/f'$ that *doesn't* mention risk aversion

Tags: curvature

$-f''(x)/f'(x)$ is known to economists as the Arrow Pratt measure of absolute risk aversion.       We want to use it in a paper to capture a scale invariant notion of concavity while specifcally avoiding any term that suggests we are talking about risk.    There is an interesting discussion of this issue in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681364/curvature-and-the-arrow-pratt-absolute-risk-coefficient) but sadly it doesn't answer my particular question about terminology

Comment: Well it's the additive inverse of the logarithmic derivative of the derivative. I don't think that helps you though.

Comment: My only suggestion is the obvious one:  just define some new symbol to denote this ratio, and refer it to using the symbol. You don't need to give it a name. Just explain that it's a measure of convexity/concavity.

Comment: Thanks!   I do like names, though.     Do you think any mathy types would complain about the word  "normalized curvature"?

Comment: I think "normalized curvature" is a bit problematic because it sounds like some sort of curvature measure, which your ratio is not (as far as I can see). How about something more vague, like "derivative ratio", or "convexity ratio", or "convexity coefficient".

Comment: we like the idea of ``normalized concavity'' but ``concavity coefficient'' would be an alternative if you think that ``normalized'' conveys the wrong idea